# Lots of inserts into SQLite database from CSV file

Tags: android, sqlite

When the user downloads my app for the first time, the app downloads a CSV file which contains about 100,000 rows of data.

Then, I would like to populate my SQLite database with it.

Here is my code:

```
InputStream inputStream = activity.openFileInput(file);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line = null;

dbHelper.beginTransaction();

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.replaceAll("'", "''").split(",");
    dbHelper.insert(values);
}

dbHelper.setTransactionSuccessful();
dbHelper.endTransaction();
dbHelper.close();
```

In my DBHelper class, here is the method insert:

```
public void insert(String[] data) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.SHAPE_ID, data[0]);
    values.put(DBHelper.SHAPE_PT_LAT, data[1]);
    values.put(DBHelper.SHAPE_PT_LON, data[2]);
    values.put(DBHelper.SHAPE_PT_SEQUENCE, data[3]);
    myDB.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_SHAPES, null, values);
}
```

I tried this code, it worked BUT it took 7 minutes to do it...
Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a better way (read faster) to populate a SQLite database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download the SQLite database file itself.

If there is other data in the database that you want to keep, you could either

- copy that other data into the downloaded database (since it is not as much data, this should be fast); or
- keep the downloaded database and the other database separated (and [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) one to the other if you need to do joins between them).

Comment: I think, this is the best solution to avoid the user to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [prepared statement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html), that should give a performance boost.
Something like:

```
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_SHAPES + " VALUES(?, ?));
```

and change your `insert()` method to do something like:

```
statement.bindString(1, data[0]);
statement.bindString(2, data[1]);
statement.executeInsert();
```

Comment: I tried it, it's better, it took about 3 minutes instead of 7 but this is still too long to me. I think I will the solution posted by CL.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://hackgeo.com/foss/sqlite-how-to-import-csv), SQLite3 has facilities to import a CSV file built-in:

```
.separator ','
.import '/path/to/csv/data' [table]
```

I'd imagine this can be done on Android using the [DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html):

DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper helper = new DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper(dbFilePath, dbTablename);
helper.prepareForInsert();
// use the bind* methods to bind your columns of CSV data to the helper in a loop
helper.execute();

I also see the the class is now marked as deprecated (API level 17) in lieu of [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html), which may or may not be relevant to your application. If you have further questions, please leave a comment.